# How to stop turtles when all patches have been colored

Tags: netlogo

When the turtles have covered the world in patches, I would like the turtles to stop on the last one so that I can record the amount of ticks it took.

Here is my code so far:

```
globals [marked-patches angle nextangle]

to setup   ca   ask patches   [ set pcolor black ]   crt turtle_amount
[set color red
    set size 1
    setxy (random 20) (random 20)]    reset-ticks
end

to go   ask turtles [
    fd 1
    rt random trt_ang
    lt random trt_ang
    if pcolor = black [set pcolor yellow]   ]   
tick end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In go, specifically in the turtle command, you can add:

```
to go   
ask turtles [
     fd 1
     rt random trt_ang
     lt random trt_ang
         if pcolor = black [
           set pcolor yellow
           if count patches with [pcolor = black] = 0 [
               stop
           ]
    ]   
]   
             tick
     end
```